# Nginx in Docker does not show correct remote address

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using nginx in a docker container and in the access logs the remote address is set to the docker internal network IP. I have tried pretty much every possible solution up until the 2nd page of google but nothing seems to make it work as expected. I would like the access logs to show adequately the real remote address so fail2ban can do its job and restrict ips that send malicious requests.
Below are the compose file and the nginx configuration

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-test
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/html/app/api
      - ./frontend:/var/www/html/app/frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - app

  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    volumes:
      - mysql_conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
    networks:
      - app

  mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - app
volumes:
  mysql_conf:
  mysql_logs:
  db_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
```

**The "web" service holds nginx, laravel application and frontend application, the build image being  php:8.0-fpm**

nginx conf (resides inside conf.d folder):

```
     upstream frontend {
         server localhost:3000;
     }

    upstream api {
        server localhost:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        error_log stderr;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        access_log stdout;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;


    # don't send the nginx version number in error pages and Server header
    server_tokens off;
    # config to don't allow the browser to render the page inside an frame or iframe
    # and avoid clickjacking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking
    # if you need to allow [i]frames, you can use SAMEORIGIN or even set an uri with ALLOW-FROM uri
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
    # when serving user-supplied content, include a X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff header along with the Content-Type: header,
    # to disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
    # https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers
    # currently suppoorted in IE > 8 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update.aspx
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx
    # 'soon' on Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471020
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout          1m;
            proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /api/v1 {
            root /var/www/html/app/api/public;
            include fastcgi_params;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        }

        # Deny .ht* access
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions or ideas?
Among other things I have tried setting explicitly the container to run in host mode did not work when adding the below configuration to the web service block:

```
    ports:
      - mode: host
        protocol: tcp
        published: 80
        target: 80
      - mode: host
        protocol: tcp
        published: 443
        target: 80
```